# efficient implementation of matlab function "imfill(BW,'holes') " in c++ not using opencv

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab

I need to implement efficiently imfill(BW,'holes') function of matlab which fills the "holes" in binary images(0,1).

Binary image is represented as a 2D matrix of 0 and 1s, where 1 represents white(bright) region and 0 represents black(dark) region.

Hole is basically a "dark" region surrounded by "bright" regions. In other words 0s surrounded by 1s is a "hole". Another defintion for hole is : a dark region(0s) which cannot be reached through any of the four edges unless we cross some bright region(1s). Edges are always black(0s).

Now I need to find holes(0s surrounded by 1s) and fill those holes(make those 0s as 1s).

Is there any efficient algorithm possible?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Example:
You can follow the link below for an example:[go to the bottom of the page and expand example: Fill Holes in a Binary Image](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/imfill.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that simple method is:

- do [FloodFill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) from some edge point with background value (repeat while non-filled background edge pixels exist)
- create mask with floodfilled pixels
- paint all except for masked with foreground color

Comment: It is not enough to start from "some background point", as the background could be made of several disjoint parts. You have to try all (so far unfilled) edge pixels

Comment: @Yves Daoust I see this problem, but there is no general solution for all situations (for example, big donut touching window edges produces 5 background regions)

Comment: @Yves Daoust OK, this approach seems reliable

Comment: Alternatively, you can surround the image with a one-pixel large outline of the background color, and fill from there.

Comment: @Yves Daoust this is exactly what I followed and it works. But I am wondering if there's some better method. Because in this one you need to check the all neighbours of a pixel everytime, which could be avoided, if possible, using some sequential access of pixels, if there's one.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, flood fill is optimal, because you have to check every pixel inside the area to be filled so that it is an `Omega(N)` problem, and flood fill answers it in `O(N)` time.

If what worries you is the fact that you will visit 4 or 8 neighbors for every pixel, have a look at the alternatives in the Wikipedia page. In particular scanline fill (but IMO, the statement "Efficiency: each pixel is checked once" is wrong.)

It is also possible to design a pure scan fill with a single visit per pixel by compressing the image into runs that you will group using a [connected component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) approach.

Raw speed of any of these methods will depend on the quality of the implementation, no a priori rule can be given.

Also look at the seed fill algorithms [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol1/CMC/Graphics_Gems_1,ed_A.Glassner.pdf).

Comment: Scanline fill won't solve the problem. For it, you need to know the polygon you are filing in and knowing that polygon ("perimeter" of the hole) is the task.

Comment: and seed fill is also a unrelated type of problem. But thanks for the efforts. I guess the flood fill approach will suffice.

Comment: @gmaster: I don't appreciate your commenting without reading my references. The scanline fill in Wikipedia is a flood fill algorithm, optimized to lower the number of accesses. And seedfill is a synonym for flood fill.